# MouseArea's parent in the GroupBox

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qqmlcomponent

What is the parent of `MouseArea`, when it in the `GroupBox`? `parent` refers to some `container`:

```
GroupBox {
    width: 100; height: 100
    id: rec
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton | Qt.RightButton
        onClicked: {
            console.log("\tparent" + parent + "\trec" + rec)
        }
    }
}
```

> qml:   parentQQuickItem_QML_15(0x3ad3590, "container") recGroupBox_QMLTYPE_12(0x3ad2790)

When the `MouseArea` in the `Rectangle`, `Rectangle` is its parent:

```
Rectangle {
    width: 100; height: 100
    id: rec
    color: "green"
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton | Qt.RightButton
        onClicked: {
            console.log("\tparent" + parent + "\trec" + rec)
        }
    }
}
```

> qml:   parentQQuickRectangle(0x39d0cd0)    recQQuickRectangle(0x39d0cd0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is common behaviour, in most QML controls (and windows), that an inner item takes up all the children of the control itself. It happens for [`Window`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#contentItem-attached-prop), [`ScrollView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-scrollview.html#contentItem-prop), [`Flickable`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flickable.html#contentItem-prop) and even `GroupBox`. Such a component is available as a property (usually) called [`contentItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-groupbox.html#contentItem-prop).

If you write an example which prints such a property you'll see that `contentItem` is the parent you are searching for:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: container

    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    property int clicksCounter: 0

    GroupBox {
        width: 100; height: 100
        id: rec
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton | Qt.RightButton
            onClicked: {
                console.log("\tparent " + parent + "\tcontentItem " + rec.contentItem)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> qml:   parent QQuickItem_QML_26(**0x1411fc0**, "container")    contentItem QQuickItem_QML_26(**0x1411fc0**, "container")

Comment: Thanks! If I want to refer to `GroupBox` from `MouseArea`, I should only use `GroupBox`s `id`, should I?

Comment: Yeah, the id not the parent property.